# How i can select build options in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile one project for `x86`,  something like the code sample `.pro` file below. How can I compile with x86 or arm?

```
x86 {
INCLUDEPATH += fo
LIBS += fo
DEFINES += CONFIG_ARM }
arm {
INCLUDEPATH += foo1
LIBS += foo2
DEFINES += CONFIG_ARM }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your pro file, the following syntax should work:

```
equals(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86) {
    message( "It's x86" )
    # Add specific x86 stuff here
}

equals(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, arm) {
    message( "It's armeabi-v7a" )
    # Add specific arm stuff here
}
```

If you are targetting Android, `QMAKE_TARGET.arch` may be changed to `ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH`.
Actually, you should first use `message` to identify what is the right variable to use in your case and then use the correct one in the `equals` statement. For instance:

```
message (ANDROID:$$ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH)
message (HOST:$$QMAKE_HOST)
message (HOST:$$QMAKE_HOST.arch)
message (TARGET:$$QMAKE_TARGET)
message (TARGET:$$QMAKE_TARGET.arch)
```

Then check the message tab to see what's in each variable.

Comment: i fixed my problem but you changed message QMAKE_TARGET.arch instead of QMAKE_TARGET and add additional argumans QMAKE_TARGET+=foo  and should be equals(QMAKE_TARGET, foo) {
    message( "It's foo" )
    # Add specific x86 stuff here
}

Answer (score 1):

Platforms/Architectures are defined in the `mkspecs` folder in Qt installation path: `$QTDIR/mkspecs`

for example:

`C:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\mkspecs` // Qt Windows

`~/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/mkspecs` // Qt Linux

Qt uses the `QMAKE_PLATFORM` ...`QMAKE_TARGET` .. directives for identifiable platforms/architectures, so you can find out if your specific platform/architecture has a defined tag by looking in the files corresponding to your kit under `mkspecs/common` folder, for example to list all supported platform tags in a Qt version:

```
cd C:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\mkspecs\common
```

`find "QMAKE_PLATFORM" *.conf | find "="`

```
QMAKE_PLATFORM          = integrity
QMAKE_PLATFORM          = integrity
QMAKE_PLATFORM          = integrity
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += ios
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += linux
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += mac darwin
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += macos osx macx
QMAKE_PLATFORM          = win32
QMAKE_PLATFORM          = qnx $$QMAKE_PLATFORM
QMAKE_PLATFORM          += solaris
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += tvos
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += uikit
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += unix posix
QMAKE_PLATFORM         += watchos
```

And to list all supported architecture tags:

```
find "QMAKE_TARGET" *.conf | find "QMAKE_TARGET"

contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
```

Comment: you can try this as well: `grep -e QMAKE_PLATFORM *.conf | cut -d' ' --complement -s -f1`

Answer (score 0):

In the .pro file, you may define specific settings depending on the platform you are using, such as which libraries to use, the includepaths, and so on. I'm not sure x86 is a valid identifier though. It should be WIN32, or since Qt5:

```
contains(QT_ARCH,i386)
```

Anyways, you are trying to compile for a specific platform which is something totally different. What you are looking for is the right compiler to do the job. Check out the kit details in the settings dialog (the Kits tab in the Build and Run options). There you can choose the compiler of your choice. If the compiler is not present, you'll have to install it.